# Angular Directive Dynamic Template & Controller When Watch Called based on Data

Tags: angularjs

*I need to Replace directive Template URL and Controller also when **templateName** changed* or Its Better to Refresh Entire directive when $scope.$watch is called.

Please Give the solution.

## Following is My Directive

```
    .directive("titleContent", function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          titleInfo: "=",
          templateName: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, scope) {
          $scope.$watch('titleInfo', function (data) {
            scope.titleInfo = data;
          });
          $scope.$watch('templateName', function (data) {
            scope.templateName = data;
          });
          
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/common/title/common.overview.html',
        controller: function(scope){
          if(scope.templateName === 'OVERVIEW'){
            return "CommonOverviewController";
          }
          else if(scope.templateName === 'contacts'){
            console.log("change Controller Detected");
          }
        },
        controllerAs: "titleContentCtrl"
      };
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change the content based on the templateName?

Comment: What are you doing differently that you can't use the `ng-include` directive?

Comment: yes, I want to change the content based on the templateName.
here i need to change controller also.